# Calling method inside setOnAction's event and evaluating of the commands

Tags: java, events, methods

Here is my code:

```
noProxyButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            this.setStatusField("Deactivating proxy...");
            System.out.println("Deactivating proxy...");
            String request = "powershell.exe  "
                        + "-Command \"Set-ItemProperty "
                        + "-path \'HKCU:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\' "
                        + "ProxyEnable -value 0";
            try {
                this.runIt(request);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MLSOps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

...

    public void setStatusField(String value){
            statusField.setText(value);
        }
```

The problem is that `setStatusField` is called after the end of the `e` event. Classic print on output is evaluating and showed 'before' calling `runIt`.

Why `setStatusField` is called so late?

Answer (score 0):

just use the threads. Not sure if it is "clear" from "programming rules" perspective (maybe someone can answer that) , but it works:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   MLSOps.setStatusField("Deactivating proxy...");
               } 
            });
            t1.start();


Thread t2 = new Thread (new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
            try {
                runIt();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MLSOps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }   
            } 
            });
            t2.start();
```